# Gravitational Teleport error on adding remote nodes

Tags: teleport

Just installed for the first time Teleport (ver. 8.0.1) on an Ubuntu 20.04 VM. I'm able to login into the web UI.
Now I'm trying to add a remote node to the main server (bastion).
Following the docs, when trying to add node, this error shows up:

```
INFO [PROC:1] Connecting to the cluster NODE1 with TLS client certificate. service/connect.go:132
ERRO [PROC:1] Node failed to establish connection to cluster: Failed to connect to Auth Server directly or over tunnel, no methods remaining.. service/connect.go:68
```

BTW, there's no firewall enabled (neither system nor cloud firewall).

To add a node, I did the following:

1. SSH into bastion server and ran: `tctl tokens add --type=node`
2. SSH into node server and ran:
   `sudo teleport start --roles=node --token=XXX --ca-pin=XXX --auth-server=SERVER_FQDN_NAME:3025`

Is this the proper way to add a node? (the official docs are quite confusing... some say that this last command should be performed in the bastion host, some other say in the node host... and also pointing to different ports 3025 in this case or 443 in others)

Comment: This question is off-topic on Stack Overflow since it is not programming-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right command to issue on the node server is: `sudo teleport start --roles=node --auth-server=https://your.domain.tld:443 --token=TOKEN`

Port `3025` should be used only when installing both the Teleport bastion (master) and the Teleport node on a virtual private network (like AWS VPC).

Comment: I have the case where the node and bastion are on the same host. The bastion is running in a docker and port :3025 is exposed, but `--auth-server=localhost:3025` still results in this error. I can connect to the port from the command line, so it's really open...
Connecting to the public :443 port also fails, likely because that's behind a traefik proxy...

Comment: Reinstalled Teleport 8 on a fresh VPC in Digital Ocean, all installation went without any issues, public SSL cert works fine and is trusted, but running the `teleport start --roles=node --auth-server=https://mydomain:443 --token=[newtoken]` still gives me this same "Node failed to establish connection to cluster: Failed to connect to Auth Server directly or over tunnel, no methods remaining.."
Very confusing what's really going wrong. I can perfectly CURL to that URL and get a response back.

Comment: @JoepBeusenberg on the remote node delete the directory `/var/lib/teleport` and restart Teleport service.
Check syslog for any errors.

Comment: Thanks, @Roberto Jobet. That did the trick indeed!
The certificate pinning is quite strict, and the logging... well, let's say there's room for improvement. :)